# Confusion with path name variable in routes.rb and .html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So in my routes.db file I map the uri "todos/delete" to "todos#delete", and assign it as the variable :delete.

```
match "todos/delete" => "todos#delete", :as => :delete, via: [:get, :post]
```

How come in my index.html.erb file, when I want to use the link_to helper method, I have to use the variable `delete_path` instead of `delete`?

```
<%= link_to "Delete last todo", delete_path %>
```

Comment: Because that's what rails does. It implicitly adds `_path` to your path.

Answer (score 1):

The name is used by the url helpers. You wind up with `delete_path` and `delete_url` depending upon what you require.

Have a look at [rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code).